# Unable to deploy ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1) to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, asp.net-core, continuous-deployment

I have a ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1) solution here in [GitHub](https://github.com/nabinked/NResumeMaker) which has multiple projects in it. I have been able to build and publish the project just fine on my local machine. But I am not able to publish the same project on my azure web app.
I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5), [this](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html), [this](http://blog.dudak.me/2015/deploying-asp-net-5-application-to-azure-web-app-using-git-or-mercurial/), [this](http://devonburriss.me/aspnet-vsonline-ci/) and a [lot more](http://tattoocoder.azurewebsites.net/asp-net-5-continuous-integration-with-travis-ci-tutum-docker-webhooks-and-azure/). I tried doing direct ftp publishing, custom deployment scripts,just XCOPY command on the custom script to copy published files from repository to site folder in azure. But nothing seems to work.
The continuous deployment within azure gives me an error "`could not find a part of the path` while doing `dnu publish` in the deployment script of azure every time.

Even when I am directly copying and pasting the locally published files to azure site folder via ftp. The site won't run.

I just want to have the site deployed on azure and if possible with continuous integration.

I have spend 2 days trying to figure out a solution. And I have given up on it now. Any help and directions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. I answered my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526538/deploy-net-core-project-on-azure-metadata-file-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment62952240_37526538. it does not give you a continuous integration but maybe it will help you with the future investigation of this problem..

Answer (score 0):

What .NET Framework version are you compiling against. Sometime back I ran into this and finding the real cause took me a bit. The cloud service guest OS are behind a bit see [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/).