# Deploy .NET Core project on Azure: Metadata file could not be found

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core API that has several dependencies. Everything builds fine on my local machine. When I try to deploy it on Azure I'm getting errors that start with the first project with dependencies:

`Metadata file 'D:\home\site\repository\artifacts\bin\MyProject.EventStore\MyProject.Bus\bin\Release\dnx451\MyProject.Bus.dll' could not be found [D:\home\site\repository\MyProject.EventStore\MyProject.EventStore.xproj]`

According to the log `MyProject.Bus` project builds without errors. 
What concerns me is that in the log output I have noticed this:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "D:\home\site\repository\MyProject.EventStore" --configuration Release --no-dependencies --build-base-path "D:\home\site\repository\artifacts\bin\MyProject.EventStore"
```

I'm not sure why Azure builds projects with `--no-dependencies` key

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to deploy my project from Github repository by using CI that is supported by Azure Web App

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Were you able to track anything down?

Comment: @DouglasLudlow I've just answer this question. Maybe it is not a solution you're looking for but at least it's something...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this but it does seem that there is no way to set deployment from a repository by adding a link to the repository on GitHub when you're using .NET Core 1. In my case at least I managed to find a documentation about deploying on Azure .NET Core 1 project. And the solution there is to use Visual Studio publish feature.

I understand that it maybe is not an exact answer to my question but if you someone is desperate to find a solution maybe this will be helpful...